# Only members can post reviews in magento

Tags: magento, review

I'm novice in Magento and I can't find the option so that only members can post reviews. I searched for about 4 hours...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

System -> Configuration -> (Catalog) Catalog -> Product Reviews -> Allow guests to write reviews -> No